# Python Plotly Treemap Color Scale Variable Not Adding Up Child Values

Tags: colors, plotly, plotly-python, treemap

I am trying to plot treemap using Plotly in Python. I have three categorical variables that I am using as parent/child variables for the plot and two other continuous variables - "Sales_Quantity" and "Sales_Amount", and I am passing one of these as "value" - represented as area, and "color" variables respectively.

Here is the sample of my data-

```
{'Category': {1171: 'Cat_1049',
  1172: 'Cat_1049',
  1173: 'Cat_1049',
  1174: 'Cat_1049',
  1175: 'Cat_1049'},
 'SubCategory_1': {1171: 6754, 1172: 6752, 1173: 6748, 1174: 6746, 1175: 6742},
 'SubCategory_2': {1171: 'MCW-145',
  1172: 'MCW-145',
  1173: 'MCW-145',
  1174: 'MCW-145',
  1175: 'MCW-141'},
 'Sales_Amount': {1171: 13509.043,
  1172: 8662.54,
  1173: 92531.29,
  1174: 11312.07,
  1175: 6427.037},
 'Sales_Quantity': {1171: 6, 1172: 4, 1173: 38, 1174: 5, 1175: 3}}
```

I was expecting the values of "color" --> "Sales Amount" of all child variables to be added up and the color of the parent boxes displayed accordingly. However, this is not happening. And the value shown on hover on the parent nodes are often lower than the "Sales Amount" on individual child nodes.

Here is the code I used-

```
fig = px.treemap(df_test, path= 
[px.Constant('All'),'Category', 'SubCategory_1','SubCategory_2'], 
                 values='Sales_Quantity',
                 color='Sales_Amount',
color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Turbo)
    fig.update_layout(legend_title="",
    autosize=False,
    width=1440,
    height=900,
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=15,
        b=10,
        t=30,
        pad=3
    ),title={'text':(f'Sales Amount and Quantities by Groups'), 
           'y':0.99,'x':0.5,'xanchor':'center',
'yanchor': 'top','font_size':20},
    #title_x=0.5,
    legend=dict(orientation="h"))

fig.show()
```

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here or if the data is not structured properly. It does not make sense why it would take care of the aggregation on the "value" variable and not on the "color" variable.

For example, the sub-categories in "Cat_1049"  have the highest "Sales Amount" of all, and the aggregate sales for this parent category is about $61.9 M. However, the color scheme is showing it as $5.4M.

Is there a way to make the colors appear the way I need it - which is for it expand the range of color scale and assign colors to the parent nodes accordingly?

[image]

I have tried some of the potential tweaks that could solve this from those found in treemap documentation - including branchvalues etc. Based on another tip - I made  sure that all NaNs were removed, reorderdered the data-frame by the three categorical columns and reset the index.  I also tried plotting using go.Treemap - which I could not even get it to display the plot in the first place.

Comment: can you include the code you used to produce your treemap? also it's preferable if you include your dataframe as formatted text – you can copy and paste the output from `df.head().to_dict()` directly into your question instead of a screenshot of your dataframe – thank you!

Comment: Derek, thank you for the help in improving my question. I have added the code I used and also the dict of the head the df.